# How to get new release updates for debian ( 7.1)

Tags: debian

my sources.list file seems like this :

```
deb http://ftp.ca.debian.org/debian/ wheezy main
deb-src http://ftp.ca.debian.org/debian/ wheezy main
```

...

and executed apt-get update several times but linux version id is still 7 in /etc/os-release e.g

```
PRETTY_NAME="Debian GNU/Linux 7 (wheezy)"
NAME="Debian GNU/Linux"
VERSION_ID="7"
VERSION="7 (wheezy)"
ID=debian
ANSI_COLOR="1;31"
HOME_URL="http://www.debian.org/"
SUPPORT_URL="http://www.debian.org/support/"
BUG_REPORT_URL="http://bugs.debian.org/"
```

I am looking for exact steps to get the latest updates(7.1)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`apt-get update` just updates the list of available packages. You need to use `apt-get upgrade` or possibly even `apt-get dist-upgrade` to actually upgrade the packages. Or use `aptitude`.

Also, it doesn't appear `/etc/os-release` changes in 7.1; `/etc/debian_version` does, though. So does the output of `lsb_release -r`.

Comment: derobert thanks, I did as you said after adding this entry to source.list `# proposed additions for a 7 point release `
`deb http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian wheezy-proposed-updates main contrib non-free` `sudo apt-get update` `sudo apt-get upgrade`

Comment: `"proposed-updates"` isn't official part of the stable tree yet and may still break (they haven't quite finished testing yet, hence 'proposed'. You *do* want to add the security updates repository to your list, though: `deb http://security.debian.org/ wheezy/updates main contrib non-free`

Comment: Shadur , please check this `http://www.debian.org/releases/stable/errata`, If I have done sth wrong how I be able to revert those changes or updates i have got from "proposed-updates".